# How do we find the eigenvalues of the matrix?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

We have the $m \times m$ matrix $$A=\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & 1 &  &  & 0 \\ 
1 & -2 & 1 &  & \\ 
 & \dots & \dots & \dots & \\ 
 &  & 1 & -2 & 1 \\ 
0 &  &  & 1 & -2 
\end{bmatrix}$$ How do we find that the eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \dots , \lambda_m$ are negative and given by $$\lambda_j=-2+2\cos \frac{j \pi}{m+1} \ \ , \ \ j=1, \dots , m$$ ??

Comment: The matrix is negative definite, thus all the eigenvalues are negative. To derive this expression I suggest you read the following file: http://www.cems.uvm.edu/~tlakoba/math337/proof_eigensystem_tridiagonal.pdf